# how to parse a text file into a list in python

Tags: python, list

I have a text file that looks like as follows:

```
abc
ade
rgh
lss
foxp3
```

I need to parse it with python into list or a dictionary, so I can get:

```
list[0] = abc
list[1] = ade
list[3] = rgh
```

I tried tika, but it gives me a list and all the items in the list are identified by one index.

```
list[0]= 
          abc
          ade
          rgh
```

here is the code:

```
new_file_name = 'main_gene_names_3adera.txt'
raw1 = parser.from_file(new_file_name)

import nltk.data

tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
data1 = raw1['content']

from nltk import sent_tokenize

print(sent_tokenize(data1))#
b1 = sent_tokenize(data1)
#print(b1[0])
```

Comment: hello, welcome to SO. Can you show us your code please ?

Comment: ``new_file_name='main_gene_names_3adera.txt'
raw1= parser.from_file(new_file_name)
import nltk.data
tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
data1 = raw1['content']
from nltk import sent_tokenize
print (sent_tokenize(data1))#
b1=sent_tokenize(data1)
print(b1[0])

Comment: Are you familiar with the file method [`readlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)? Even simpler you can just do `list(file)`...

Comment: And please [edit] that into the question, don't use comments

Comment: @Tomerikoo `list(file)` will keep the trailing `\n`s.

Comment: @bereal well for that matter also `readlines()` will lol